# SQLite - merge table from 2 databases but do not add new entries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm on a Linux based OS with sqlite and I have 2 database files:
I want to update the entries in databaseA with the those in databaseB but I don't want to add new entries to databaseA.

This for example is good but it will add new entries which I don't want.

```
attach "databaseB" as db2; insert or replace into main.MyTable select * from db2.MyTable;
```

So I want to set some key like "name" and "family name" and if it's the same in both database update all the other fields for this raw, if there is no such name + family name in databaseA do nothing.

What's the preferred way to do this?

Comment: You are looking for `UPDATE`. You want to update table A records with table B records. Does every record in table A have a match in B? Is `name` + `family_name` unique in both tables or can one table have duplicate entries?

Comment: There are some entries which are only in table A and some which are only in table B. name + family_name are unique in both

Comment: Are you suggesting something like this :

`attach "databaseB" as db2; update main.MyTable
set column1 = (select db2.MyTable.column1
             from db2.MyTable
            where main.MyTable.name = db2.MyTable.name
            and  main.MyTable.family_name = db2.MyTable.family_name);

set column2 = (select db2.MyTable.column2
             from db2.MyTable
            where main.MyTable.name = db2.MyTable.name
            and  main.MyTable.family_name = db2.MyTable.family_name);
`

and so on for each column..

Comment: With some A entries possibly missing in B, you would have to join both tables in the update, so as to only access A records that have a match in B. I don't know the related update syntax in SQLite though and have no time to look it up right now.

Answer (score 0):

Just restrict the replacing to those rows whose key is found in the other table, using either a subquery:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO main.MyTable
SELECT *
FROM db2.MyTable
WHERE (Name, FamilyName) IN (SELECT Name, FamilyName
                             FROM main.MyTable);
```

or a join:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO main.MyTable
SELECT db2.MyTable.*
FROM db2.MyTable
JOIN main.MyTable USING (Name, FamilyName);
```